# Connect MQ Series from JBoss using MQ Java Classes

Tags: jboss, ibm-mq, mq

I am trying to connect to MQ Series from Jboss Server. Can anyone tell me what are the steps should I follow?
Breaking my head for nearly a week !!!

Comment: You should really provide in more detail the steps you have already taken, and which actual problems you are facing if you want to get an answer here.

Comment: Can you connect to the queue using other tools, for example Python pymqi module? Look at my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536733/how-to-connect-to-local-mqseries-queue-using-python

Comment: what version of Jboss? what version of MQ? need to be specific.

Answer (score 0):

Just check

1. http://community.jboss.org/wiki/IntegrationWithWebSphereMQSeries
2. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0710_ritchie/0710_ritchie.html